ObjectBox 4 C++ Initialise in memory database
I have created an ObjectBox database and written some records to tables which are in base/data.mdb
A different program needs to read this database into an in memory instance of ObjectBox.
Creating the store and pointing to the file does not work:
store_(obx::Options(create_obx_model()).directory("memory:/databasePath"))

I tried creating a temporary store then copy the values to the in memory database
tempStore_(obx::Options(create_obx_model()).directory("path/to/base"))
obx::Box<Object> tableTemp(tempStore_);

memStore_(obx::Options(create_obx_model()).directory("memory:/databasePath"))
obx::Box<Object> tableObject(memStore_);

auto all = tableTemp.getAll();
tableObject.put(all);

But get error:
what():  ID is higher or equal to internal ID sequence: 3 (vs. 1). Use ID 0 (zero) to insert new objects.

Is there a way to initialise in memory database from file? Can I change the internal ID sequence to the last of the in memory database, rather than insert dummy objects and then delete them to increase the sequence number.

You have to make the ID property "assignable". Let me quote the property annotation docs for additional details:

assignable IDs (set as id(assignable)) to switch from the default
(ObjectBox assigns object IDs during insert, following auto-increment
order). This will allow putting an object with any valid ID. You can
still set the ID to zero to let ObjectBox auto-assign a new ID.

For example, in the fbs file (assuming you are using ObjectBox Generator) it should look like this:
table MyEntity {
    /// objectbox:id(assignable)
    id:ulong;
}

